# How to draw on the top of an inherited widget (VlcVideoWidget)?

Tags: qt, qt4, z-index, vlc, vlc-qt

How can I draw something on a VLC Video Widget?

I'm using [VLC-Qt](http://projects.tano.si/vlc-qt) library to play video on a widget in my Qt application. My application requires drawing a text (or something like) on all videos. I already tried subclassing `VlcWidgetVideo` and reimplementing `paintEvent`. The method works when no video is playing. Though immadiately after starting to play, my paintings disappear. It looks like they are under VLC's video...

The code:

```
class TrackerWidgetVideo : public VlcWidgetVideo{
// Blah blah blah
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
}
// .......
void TrackerWidgetVideo::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    VlcWidgetVideo::paintEvent(e);
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Some foo goes here"); // This paints
}
```

Following images describe the situation better. First screenshot is when no video is playing. Second one is when I open a video file.

[image: When not playing video]

[image: Playing a video]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to create an overlay. If you take a look at `WidgetVideo.cpp` in the source for vlc-qt, you can see that the `request()` method creates a widget and adds it to a layout which is parented to the `VlcVideoWidget`. This is probably messing with the overlay you're painting in your `paintEvent`.

To create an overlay that should stay on top of your video, follow the method outlined here: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_overlay_QWidget_on_top_of_another

You should add an instance of the overlay class to your instance of `TrackerWidgetVideo`. The overlay class will contain the overriden `paintEvent` method that is currently part of your `TrackerWidgetVideo`. Then, you'll override `TrackerWidgetVideo::resizeEvent` to resize your overlay class instance.

Here's some example code:

**Overlay.h**

```
class Overlay : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    Overlay(QWidget* parent);

 protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event);
};
```

**Overlay.cpp**

```
Overlay::Overlay(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setPalette(Qt::transparent);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
}

void Overlay::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Some foo goes here");
}
```

**TrackerWidgetVideo.h**

```
class TrackerWidgetVideo : public VlcWidgetVideo
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    explicit VlcWidgetVideo(QWidget* parent = NULL);

 protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event);

 private:
    Overlay* overlay;
};
```

**TrackerWidgetVideo.cpp**

```
TrackerWidgetVideo::TrackerWidgetVideo(QWidget* parent) : VlcWidgetVideo(parent)
{
    overlay = new Overlay(this);
}

void TrackerWidgetVideo::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
    overlay->resize(event->size());
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: It's the same. Only when no video is playing, text is shown. I think it's z-index issue. Isn't it?

Comment: Ok this method work, though I cant get the widget transparent.

Comment: Does the overlay widget not appear properly transparent? Can you give a screenshot of what you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

Vlc creates two "internal" widgets on VlcVideoWidget when video is playing.
Create a new widget as the VlcVideoWidget's sibling(not child), bring it to front and paint on it.