# Drawing items on VLC object

Tags: c++, qt, vlc, vlc-qt

Recently I have tried to do some graphics on the top of VLC video using vlc-qt (which provides a video widget). The approach was trying to draw something on the widget. But it failed duo to the fact that vlc-qt's widget uses an internal widget to render video. ([See more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454833/how-to-draw-on-the-top-of-an-inherited-widget-vlcvideowidget))

Now I'm trying to do something different. I want to try drawing text (or some rectangles) on the VLC media itself (not the widget). I suppose it's the way how VLC media player renders subtitles (isn't it?)

So the question is this: Having a vlc-qt interface, how can I access underlying vlc object and draw something on it [using libVLC API]?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the only way to do it with libvlc is to use `libvlc_video_set_callbacks` + `libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks`. It will decode media stream's frames to memory, which you could use as you wish.